# Java annotation, pass variable to annoted method

Tags: java, annotations

I am writing a web service in Java and some of the end points are to have authentication.

To accomplish this I have created an annotation that I can apply to any request method that needs to be authenticated, I then have a request filter that intercepts any requests with the annotation and performs authentication checks.

My question is: is it possible for the filter to set a variable in the annotation that is then accessible to the request method so I can pass user information from the authentication filter to the request method without having to perform 2 identical checks..

Essentially it would look like:

```
public @interface Authenticated {
    UserData user;
}

public Response filterRequest() //for @Authenticated methods
{
    user = doAuthentication();
    if(user == null)
        throw new UnauthorisedException();

    //Call the next method, the one with the annotation
    return Requests.next();
}

@Authenticated
public Response foo()
{
    return new Response("Hello " + user.Name);
}
```

I know its possible in other languages as I have done it in C# but I cant find any references to it in Java.
Also if possible would it work if the annotation is placed on the class rather than individual methods?

Comment: How would you get the annotation variable in your annotated method?

Comment: Why don't you store the authenticated user in a request attribute (assuming you're in a servlet environment, which is not clear from your code)